# facebook-php-sdk in a server with php 5.2

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

Is possible to use Facebook php sdk v4 in a server using php 5.2? if not, is there any way to use Facebook on this server?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This version of the Facebook SDK for PHP requires PHP 5.4 or greater.

No, you can´t use the PHP SDK v4.x on a server with PHP 5.2. You can still use the old SDK though: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk

After all the CURL calls are pretty much the same, and if you know how it works you can just use CURL on your own with the API. For example: http://www.devils-heaven.com/extended-page-access-tokens-curl/

Authorization should be done with the JavaScript SDK anyway, it´s much easier with [FB.login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/v2.1).

Comment: Are you sure it still works? When I create a new app under Facebook Developers, the default version goes to 2.5 and it doesn't seem to work with the old SDK any more.

Comment: my answer is from 2014, we´re at PHP SDK v5.x now. but yeah, i am sure it still works, because it´s simple CURL. please create a new question with more detail.